# initialized constant <name of my class> (NameError)

Tags: ruby

here's the CRUD class that's responsible for interacting with the XML file.

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML  

class Crud
  @users = Array.new()
  def self.get_allusers()
    xmlfile = File.new("Users.xml")
    doc = Document.new(xmlfile)
       XPath.each( doc, "//user") do |e|
         user = {:id => e.element['id'], :firstname => e.element['firstname'], :lastname => e.element['lastname']}
         @users << user     
       end
    end
  end
```

And this is how I am trying to access the method from a different file.

```
users = Crud.new()
puts users.get_allusers()
```

I'm getting the following error: **"initialized constant Crud (NameError)"**. And I have no idea what that means. Because I've also tried to access the method this way:

```
puts Crud.get_allusers()
```

What's wrong with the code? What am I supposed to initialize?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different file needs to require or load the crud file, otherwise the constant is not defined.  Classes in Ruby are constants, so the contant that is not defined in this case is the Crud class.

Comment: Crud class is defined in Crud.rb, so how do I define it? Can u give some code, please?